# Shouldn't TypeScript thrown an error when an invalid type is passed to an object?

Tags: typescript, interface

I have defined a MapInterface that should require the properties `fileIndex`, `mapId`, `width` and `height`. I'm expecting an error to be thrown if any of these properties are excluded, however, given the code below, no exception is thrown.

```
# MapInterface.ts
export default interface MapRequest {
  fileIndex: number,
  mapId: number,
  width: number,
  height: number
}

# Map.ts
export default class Map {
  constructor(options: MapRequest) {
      //Constructor logic
  }
}

# Test.js
// Excluding width & height should throw an error?
const map = new Map({fileIndex: 1, mapId: 1})
```

Comment: The compiler errors out here: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=export%20default%20interface%20MapRequest%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20fileIndex%3A%20number%2C%0D%0A%20%20mapId%3A%20number%2C%0D%0A%20%20width%3A%20number%2C%0D%0A%20%20height%3A%20number%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aexport%20default%20class%20Map%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20constructor(options%3A%20MapRequest)%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2FConstructor%20logic%0D%0A%20%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20Excluding%20width%20%26%20height%20should%20throw%20an%20error%3F%0D%0Aconst%20map%20%3D%20new%20Map(%7BfileIndex%3A%201%2C%20mapId%3A%201%7D)

Comment: My IDE complains as expected. Coming from a PHP background I was expecting a runtime error. Is that possible with TypeScript?

Comment: TypeScript doesn't exist at runtime, it all compiles to JavaScript